# Why there is a potential difference only across resistors?

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, electrical-resistance, voltage

I don't understand why there is a potential difference only across resistors, shouldn't the electrons convert potential energy all the way to the other side of the circuit just like a ball would do all the way to the ground?  please I need help, I'm confused for days!.

my understanding and doubts are based on the following explanations:

https://youtu.be/k9SwNST1eW0?t=41

https://youtu.be/3zt7DWUiaDE?t=82

Answer (score 2):

In theory, the wire has no resistance, which makes you confused about the potential difference. In fact, the wire must have some resistance in it, so the electric potential drops along the circuit.
However, we can sum up all the resistance of the wires to one resistor and assume the wires have no resistance to make the problem simpler for solving.

Comment: ooh! makes sense now
Thank you!

Comment: but wouldn't that make our calculation for only the voltage across the resistor not accurate since it's the sum of all the resistance (the wire + the resistor)?

Comment: @michelandru All calculations are approximate. If you have a meter of AWG 22 wire, which is thin enough that it can be delicate to work with, its resistance is about 50 milli-ohms. Shorter or fatter wires have even less resistance.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand why there is a potential difference only across
> resistors

The problem is your videos only discuss resistance. They do not discuss capacitors and inductors. There is a potential difference across capacitors and inductors (for time varying currents) as well for resistors. For a capacitor

$$v(t)=\frac{1}{C}\int i(t)dt$$

For an inductor

$$v(t)=L\frac{di(t)}{dt}$$

> shouldn't the electrons convert potential energy all the way to the
> other side of the circuit just like a ball would do all the way to the
> ground?

They do.

The main difference is that resistors convert that energy into heat,  whereas energy is stored in the electric fields of capacitors and magnetic fields of inductors, respectively. The sum of the energies dissipated in resistors and stored in capacitors and inductors equals the initial potential energy given the electrons. The stored energies are, for capacitors and inductors, resepectively,

$$E_{C}=\frac{1}{2}CV^2$$

$$E_{L}=\frac{1}{2}LI^2$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does! Thank you